# CircularProgress Indicator in flutter applied in Elevated button?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add elevated with circularprogressIndicator

I want to add this circular Progress Indicator in my sign up option this is my container for sign up option

```
Container(
        height: 45,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)))),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: ()   async {
            String res = await AuthMethods().signUpUser(
                email: _emailController.text,
                password: _passwordController.text,
                username: _usernameController.text,
                bio: _bioController.text,
                file: _image!);
            print(res);
          },
          child:  Text("Sign up"),
        ),
      ),
```

where should i add circular Progress indicator  this is code for "_isLoading
? const Center(
child: CircularProgressIndicator(
color: Colors.white,
),
)
:"
So when i click on sign up button it run as circularprogressIndicator on it .

Answer (score 0):

We can display a circular progress indicator when the signup process is ongoing.

```
bool _isLoading = false; // Define this boolean to track loading state

Container(
  height: 45,
  width: double.infinity,
  decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
    ),
  ),
  child: _isLoading
      ? Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        )
      : ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            setState(() {
              _isLoading = true; // Set loading state to true
            });

            String res = await AuthMethods().signUpUser(
              email: _emailController.text,
              password: _passwordController.text,
              username: _usernameController.text,
              bio: _bioController.text,
              file: _image!,
            );
            
            print(res);

            setState(() {
              _isLoading = false; // Set loading state to false when signup is complete
            });
          },
          child: Text("Sign up"),
        ),
)
```